# directory not found for option '-f WARNING after updating to XCode5

Tags: xcode, cocoa, compiler-warnings

Since I have updated to XCode 5 for my OSX Project I get the following warning and I don't know why and how to solve it:

```
Ld /Users/thomaswickl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickQuick2-aniutiuhasvwojftbgyjcsdqtxzw/Build/Products/Debug/QuickQuick2.app/Contents/MacOS/QuickQuick2 normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/thomaswickl/Development/Git Projects/quickquick2/QuickQuick2"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.9
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L/Users/thomaswickl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickQuick2-aniutiuhasvwojftbgyjcsdqtxzw/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/thomaswickl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickQuick2-aniutiuhasvwojftbgyjcsdqtxzw/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/thomaswickl/Development/Git\ Projects/quickquick2/QuickQuick2 -F\"/Users/thomaswickl/Development/Git\ Projects/quickquick2/QuickQuick2/..\" -F/Users/thomaswickl/Development/Git\ Projects/quickquick2 -filelist /Users/thomaswickl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickQuick2-aniutiuhasvwojftbgyjcsdqtxzw/Build/Intermediates/QuickQuick2.build/Debug/QuickQuick2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QuickQuick2.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/../Frameworks -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Carbon -framework Rebel -framework Accounts -framework Social -framework MapKit -framework Cocoa -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/thomaswickl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickQuick2-aniutiuhasvwojftbgyjcsdqtxzw/Build/Intermediates/QuickQuick2.build/Debug/QuickQuick2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QuickQuick2_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/thomaswickl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickQuick2-aniutiuhasvwojftbgyjcsdqtxzw/Build/Products/Debug/QuickQuick2.app/Contents/MacOS/QuickQuick2


ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F"/Users/thomaswickl/Development/Git Projects/quickquick2/QuickQuick2/.."'
```

I'm lost since I don't understand this warning. Any Idea what this means and how I can solve this warning? The Application launches but the warning is annoying and I treat warnings as errors.

Comment: It may be because of the space in directory name "Git Projects". Command "cd" is not understanding it. Just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Terminal window type `man ld` and you'll get a description of the `ld` command and the arguments it takes. There you'll find `-F` specifies a directory to search for frameworks in. The Xcode generated command line contains:

```
-F/Users/thomaswickl/Development/Git\ Projects/quickquick2/QuickQuick2
-F\"/Users/thomaswickl/Development/Git\ Projects/quickquick2/QuickQuick2/..\"
-F/Users/thomaswickl/Development/Git\ Projects/quickquick2
```

The second entry is actually redundant - it is the same as the third (as `..` means parent) - but it looks like your problem is the way the path is escaped. To allow a space in a path you can either enclose it in quotes or precede the space with a backslash. Paths 1 & 3 use the backslash method, path 2 uses both and so the backslash is presumably treated as a literal character (that is what would happen in Terminal) and therefore the path is incorrect... (cross-eyed yet? ;-))

Maybe this double-escaping was introduced when the project was converted to Xcode 5. The paths are listed in your project's settings (sorry Xcode not to hand), hunt it out and remove it (as its a duplicate).

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you delete Framework Search Paths from build settings in under Tests in aTrget.